# store python plot as a variable and reload it to overlay another plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica you can store plots in variables and then overlay them at some later time. For example,

```
plt1 = Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,Pi}];
plt2 = Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi}];
plt3 = Plot[x,{x,0,Pi}];

Show[plt1,plt2]
Show[plt1,plt3]
```

gives two plots, one overlays cos(x) and sin(x) plots, and the other overlays cos(x) and x plots. Therefore, I do not need to replot cos(x) for the second overlay since it is already saved in plt1.

I am wondering the same thing can happen in python too. I have a 2D function that is time-consuming to plot, and I need to replot it and overlay it with some other data every time. Can I plot it only once and then overlay it in with plots of other data?

Comment: I am not certain this can be done with matplotlib as it creates an image for its plots. Mathematica (a.k.a Wolfram Language) can do this because of its box language which makes it easy for the front end to combine multiple plots by their underlying elements.

Answer (score 0):

I will interprete the question as to ask about matplotlib (since it is tagged by that), but there are of course other python plotting tools, which might behave differently.

In matplotlib an artist (e.g. a line) is necessarily part of exactly one figure. You cannot add the same artist to more than one figure.
So the usual solution is to not wanting to duplicate the artist itself, but rather the procedure to create the artist.

```
def mycos(x, ax=None, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.plot(x, np.cos(x), **kwargs)

def mysin(x, ax=None, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), **kwargs)

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)

# Create one figure with two subplots, plot one function in each subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2)
mycos(x, ax=axes[0])
mysin(x, ax=axes[1])

# Create another figure with one subplot, plot both functions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
mycos(x, ax=ax)
mysin(x, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are correct about matplotlib. From your code, it is my understanding that both mycos and mysin are called twice in the code, while I am interested in a situation that we call them only once, store each corresponding plot in a variable, and afterward, we only call those variables (similar to the Mathematica code) rather than replotting the functions each time.

Comment: Yes, to see n curves you call n times the function. In order not to slide into an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info) here, you may update the question with your actual problem.